# How to send mail using Python in Google App Engine (not working)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I have an app in Google app engine using jQuery and Python, it allows users to post things... I have an recover password handler in Python, I want this handler to deal with the query/data by send that user out an email. But it does not seem to work:

```
class RecoverHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #email = self.request.get('#email')
        usr = self.request.get('email')#or email
        dob = self.request.get('dob')
        name = self.request.get('maidenName')
        callback = self.request.get('callback')
        #get user from database
        #user = User.get_by_id(#email)
        user = User.get_by_id(usr)
        #if user exists check for correct password
        dobx = user.dob
        namex = user.maidenName
        if user:
            if dobx == dob:
                if namex == name:
                    self.response.write(callback + '({"response":"login Complete"})')

                    mail.send_mail(sender="Example.com Support <support@example.com>",
                    to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
                    subject="Your account has been approved",
                    body="""
                    Dear Albert:
                    Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
                    http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
                    access new features.Please let us know if you have any questions.The example.com Team""")

                else:
                    self.response.write(callback + '({"response":"login incomplete"})')
            else:
                self.response.write(callback + '({"response":"login Password incorrect"})')
        else:
            self.response.write(callback + '({"response":"login not found"})')
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? Or how it's not working

Comment: Did you read the caveats further down [the page you took that snippet from](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail)? Does your actual sender address meet one of those criteria?

Comment: Yes the sender address meets the criteria as I am the owner and developer. On the other hand the receiver is a normal address example.com, could this be a problem? do they have to have an Google Account ?

Answer (score 0):

`user = User.get_by_id(usr)` ?

is your entity's ID really their email address? Can you add some logging? `user.dob` and `user.maidenName` should throw `NoneType` errors if your ID is not the email address.

`dobx = user.dob` and `namex = user.maidenName` should go inside the `if`, so they don't throw an error if User not found.